How to allow public access for an application on google cloud workstation
I have a web application running on google cloud workstation and I am able to access the application after running my dev server. But I want to be able to receive webhook events coming into my application. Unfortunately, the workstation requires authentication so using webhooks does not work. How can I enable public access to the hosted application? I really need to test the application with the webhook and receive events.
At the moment, the only option to allow users access the workstation is to add the users to the workstation. This allows an authenticated user using a google workspace account to access the workstation but otherwise, I am not able to open up the workstation.
I expect that it should be possible to open up the workstation. Given that it's for developers and using of webhooks is a very normal use case including others during daily work. I should be able to open up an application (not the workstation itself but the application running on the port) as public.
This has resulted in not even being able to use laravel with vite dev server. The vite dev server tries to make requests to the laravel application to support hot reload and such but since the workstation url requires authentication, the request always returns a 302 with a redirect to another link which is having the authentication requirement so it's basically blocked from access. As seen in the network tab pictures below:
 and


I'm afraid what you know is already the answer. Based on this documentation which is under the feature of the Cloud Workstation, only default users have access to the workstation created. Sharing also a screenshot below from the said feature.


Thanks for this update. Yes I see that, I have just been looking for ways to resolve this issue especially when it comes to using webhooks. Is there a way to authenticate even with IAM? I tried but it did not work. I basically tried to use a valid auth token header that had access to the workstation to send an http request to the web service launched on the workstation but it did not seem to work. I was experimenting with the webhook sending the request to a cloud function and then forwarding it from the function to the workstation url with an authentication header.
